# Angular 9 - problem with mat-select, it doesn't select the current value in the options list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem, I created a `mat-select` to allow the user to switch language.
In my component, I initialize the object that saves the current selection value, and the issue is,
every time you open the `mat-select` dropdown, the "`preselected`" value from the list, will always be the first one, and not the one that was previously selected!

This also causes an issue, where I cannot click on the first one, nothing will happen if I do.
I suspect I did something wrong in the implementation of the mat-select and on how do I store the current value, can someone help me out?

**HTML**

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="rememberLang($event.value)" [(value)]="savedLang" [compareWith]="objectComparisonFunction">
        <mat-select-trigger>
          <mat-icon>language</mat-icon>
          <span>{{savedLang.text}}</span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let lang of languages" [value]="lang">{{lang.value}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
  public languages = [
    { text: "Deutsch", value: "de" },
    { text: "Italiano", value: "it" },
    { text: "Français", value: "fr" },
    { text: "English", value: "en" },
  ];

  public savedLang = {text: "", value: ""};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.remember.lastUsedLang.subscribe(l => {
      if (l) {
        this.setSavedLang(l);
      } else {
        this.savedLang = { text: "Deutsch", value: "de" };
      }
    });
  }
```

basically, when the component is fired, I check if the user has a language in `LocalStorage` and set the variable `this.savedLang` to it, otherwise if not, I set it by default to German.

I suspect my `HTML` code is wrong, everything seems to be working fine, no console errors, the only issue is, whatever language is selected, when I open the `mat-select` dropdown, the "highlight" selection will always be on the first item of the list, and not on the actual current value.

**EDIT:** **I fixed it**, the issue was, in Angular9, you need to use `[value]` instead of `[(value)]`